# Can apps be controlled through adb?

Tags: contacts, backup, adb

Can an installed application be completely controlled via adb?

For example:
Consider I need to to export my Contacts to SD Card. So here there are basically 5 Steps involved

1)Open Contacts application

2)Press Menu Key

3)Select Import/Export option

4)Select Export to SD card

5)Confirm Export

Can any/all of them be performed via adb?

This can be useful when you have an unrooted phone with a bricked display and all access you have is via adb.

Comment: Why didn't you have all your contacts sync through Gmail or Hotmail?

Comment: I prefer not giving up my contacts to google or any 3rd party for that matter.
I tried Kies but it won't detect my Galaxy S (The bricked phone)  while it works perfectly fine for Galaxy Mini.

Comment: Why not go back to your carrier's shop and get them to do it for you - they'd have the means to do this kind of thing for customers who are clumsy?

Comment: you can [generate key events](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.de/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html)  with adb. technically it should be possible to launch a thoroughly crafted series of key events to an app.

Comment: Thanks a lot ce4. It worked!
Exported my contacts to SD card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes and no. You can issue intents with `adb` but that's it. So the steps you described can't be achieved with `adb`.

Edit: [ce4](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/15713/ce4) showed a [blog post](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.de/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html) which mentions the `input` binary which is able to simulate key events.

```
adb shell input keyevent <keycode>
```