# How can one robustly and automatically configure Orbot through ADB?

Tags: adb, settings, automation, orbot

### Context

Whilst automating a calendar setup over tor, and I was looking for an open source, and more robust way to automatically configure Orbot to:
0. Allow the `Connection request` (prompt: `ok`)

1. Select the `Davx5` application to be "`torified`".
2. Start the Orbot service.

My current approach is to use simulated keypresses, as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25670/254078). However, if a call comes in, or messages popup, this may lead to unintended effects.

## Approaches

So I thought of three options:
0. Determine where the Orbot app settings are stored on the phone and modify those.

1. Pre-configure a build with the intended settings.
2. Write a termux script that performs the Orbot configuration settings.

However, the pre-compilation is somewhat involved, especially to do on arbitrary pc's that just want the calendar, and if I do it myself (once), users have to rely on my compiled file, which I prefer to avoid.

Furthermore, I did not yet find if/where the Orbot app settings/configurations are stored on a device, and whether this location is the same for each device/automatically retrievable.

### Question

How can one robustly and automatically configure Orbot through ADB?

### Notes

The device is rooted.

Comment: Have you tried to discuss this with the Orbot developers? Usually there is a mailing list, news group, Slack/IRC or whatever channel where you can contact the developers. May be they have a better idea or add a new feature.